# How do i configure azure databricks with log4j2

Tags: databricks, log4j2, azure-databricks

log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the DatabricksRollingFileAppender named 'publicFile'
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the DatabricksRollingFileAppender named 'privateFile'
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the DatabricksRollingFileAppender named 'product'
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the DatabricksRollingFileAppender named 'metrics'
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [rollingPolicy] to value "org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy".
log4j:WARN Please set a rolling policy for the DatabricksRollingFileAppender named 'usage

Comment: I am trying to update to log4j2 in the databricks environment but since the databricks environment supports the log4j.properties file and not log4j2.properties. I've updated my spring boot application to use log4j2 2.17.0 but i cannot configure on the databricks side. Any ideas ?

Comment: Databricks uses log4j 1.x, not log4j 2.x

Answer (score 1):

As of [Datatbricks runtime 11.0](https://docs.databricks.com/release-notes/runtime/11.0.html) with Spark 3.3.0, log4j has been upgraded to log4j2. I haven't seen official documentation for custom log support but this is what's been working for me.
Similar with log4j 1 support, you need a custom [init script](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) to run on the cluster and create a log4j2.properties file. This script might look something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -euxo pipefail

echo "Running on the driver? ${DB_IS_DRIVER}"
echo "Driver ip: ${DB_DRIVER_IP}"

cat >>/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/driver/log4j2.properties <<EOL

appender.customFile.type = RollingFile
appender.customFile.name = customFile
appender.customFile.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.customFile.layout.pattern = %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n%ex
appender.customFile.filePattern = logs/log4j.custom.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz
appender.customFile.policies.type = Policies
appender.customFile.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.customFile.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.customFile.fileName = logs/stdout.custom-active.log

logger.custom=DEBUG, customFile
logger.custom.name = com.custom
logger.custom.additivity = true

EOL
```

Answer (score 0):

In databricks , you can check the complete details on databricks with log4j2 in [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/12/23/log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228-research-and-assessment.html)